# Slider vertical com lista de imagens em jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, slider

Eu tenho a seguinte lista de imagens e vídeos que estão sendo puxados do banco de dados. Eu gostaria que essa "ul" ficasse subindo os itens infinitamente em um slider vertical. Não conheço muito jQuery, alguém tem ideia de como fazer esse efeito? O efeito seria assim: http://centralsigma.com.br/ (Como os banners na lateral esquerda desse site)

```
<div class="banner">
  <div class="item">
    <ul>
      <?php

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM banner ORDER BY id DESC";


      try {
        $result = $conexao->prepare($sql);
        $result->execute();

        $contar = $result->rowCount();
        if ($contar>0) {
          while ($show = $result->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $midia = $show['midia'];
            $link = $show['link'];
            $tipo = $show['tipo'];

            if ($tipo == "Imagem") {
      ?>
      <li>
        <?php if ($link != "") {
          echo '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">';
        } ?>
          <img id="myImg" src="banner/<?php echo $midia; ?>" alt="Publicidade" style="width:100%;max-width:340px; height:170px">
          <?php if ($link != "") {
            echo '</a>';
          } ?>
      </li>
    <?php } else { ?>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:modal('<?php echo $midia; ?>')" id="play"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></a>
        <img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/<?php echo $midia; ?>/mqdefault.jpg" alt="Miniatura Vídeo" style="width:100%;max-width:340px; height:170px">
      </li>
      <?php } } }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
          echo $e;
        }
      ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cara vc fala do banner com depoimentos ou do banner que tem as logos? Se for o banner das logo e vc consegue algo muito próximo só com CSS e poucas linhas de código! Nem precisa de JS ou jQuery... Se te interessar posso fazer um exemplo

Comment: @hugocsl Sim, os que tem as logos. Se puder pode mandar o exemplo

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Como o autor mudou a definição do que realmente ele precisava fiz esse outro exemplo tentando simular o `looping` do *slider*. Mas para isso eu precisei "clonar" na mão os últimos itens do conteúdo. A ideia aqui é que quando a animação fizer o `loop` o conteúdo do final é igual ao do início, assim o usuário não percebe o `loop`

Veja como ficou no exemplo.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 220px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  animation: anima 4s infinite linear;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #333;
}

@keyframes anima {
  10% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    /* 180px e a altura do container descontando as margens pode ser que vc tenha que ajustar esse tamanho dependo da altura do seu container */
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% + -180px));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/81/80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/80" alt="">
    </div>

    <!-- clones para fazer o looping -->
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/81/80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/80" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/80" alt="">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Opção idêntica a do site que o autor da pergunta tinha solicitado anteriormente**

Segue um modelo feito apenas com CSS. A ideia aqui é que eu um `.container` que dentro dele tem um outro *container* chamado `.slider`, esse por sua vez tem dentro dele todas as logos. Agora basta vc fazer o `.slider` mover para cima 100% da própria altura, para isso eu usei `transform:translateY(calc(-100% + a altura do .container))` assim o `.slider` sobe todo, mas não deixa o .conteiner vazio...

Lógica aplicada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para entender melhor veja o código: 
*(deixei uns comments no CSS, leia!)*

**OBS:** A única ressalva fica para quanto mais itens vc tiver dentro do slider, mais rápido ele vai passar. Explico: Se o Slide tem 100px de altura e tem 10s para percorrer a própria altura ele desloca 10px por Segundo. Agora se ele tiver 200px de altura em 10s ele vai deslocar agora 20px por Segundo, logo ele vai passar a animação mais rápido. Para corrigir isso basta vc aumentar o tempo da animação de 10s para 20s :D

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 220px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: anima 6s infinite alternate linear;
}
.logo {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
}

@keyframes anima {
  10% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  20% {
    /* aqui eu repito a propriedade para deixar o slide para um tempo antes de rodar */
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  90% {
    /* aqui o slide sobe 100% da própria altura, menos a altura do container */
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 220px));
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(calc(-100% + 220px));
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/81" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/81/80" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/80" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/81/80" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/80" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/81" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/81/80" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/80" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="https://unsplash.it/80/81" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Essa alternativa é boa mas n faz o efeito correto, no caso ele sobe depois volta sem deixar o container vazio, eu preciso que ele suba e logo após o último item venha o primeiro novamente, um loop infinito.

Comment: @C.Oli cara eu fiz exatamente igual ao banner do site que vc indicou. Se vc olhar lá vai ver que o banner deles é igual, sobe e desce, Não fica nesse "looping" que vc está falando ai não... repara lá

Comment: Realmente, eu não havia reparado. O problema é só esse looping. O teu método funcionou direitinho aqui.

Comment: @C.Oli da uma olhada no *EDIT* que eu fiz, coloquei um novo código lá no inicio com a animação fazendo o looping

Comment: mesmo com essa alteração ainda não surgiu o efeito esperado, ele fica vazio, vou continuar procurando e caso ache a solução posto aqui.

Comment: @C.Oli acho que com CSS vai ser difícil algo muito melhor que isso. Mas vale a pesquisa, as vezes aparece algo que te serva, principalmente se for com JS... Mas esse modelo que postei ai não deixa espaço vazio não, basta executar o exemplo, se ai ficou vazio é pq vc não ajustou o CSS pro tamanho do seu container e dos elementos.